"to reign" vs. "to rule"
What is the difference in meaning between reign and rule in the following quote:

The Shah, an earnest young man full of good intentions, cannot make up his mind whether he should reign or rule, and consequently does neither.

The source is here - this quote has been used over and over in the history books, dealing with foreign exploitation of Iran during the last Shah's reign.
My guess is that reigning is holding the title, while not necessarily exercising actual political power, like the British King. I am looking for a definitive answer however.

Did you look up the meanings of the two terms in a dictionary.

Your guess is perfectly good. But note that in practice, no British monarch has had any such choice for well over a century. The only choices British royalty get is reign or abdicate - British people are ruled by Parliament and/or shadowy forces, not monarchs (who are really just titular heads of state, in effectively ceremonial roles). Things are different in Iran, obviously. I didn't read much of your link, but what I did scan doesn't seem to mention the real power in Iran - an autocratic / despotic "clergy". But your cited writer thinks the Shah had choices, and what do I know?

@FumbleFingers, I suspect the sentence in question was written decades before the clerical takeover or power. The last shah's reign began in 1941 when he was 21.
